# Hoeffding's inequality proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

I was reading proof of Hoeffding's inequality, I couldn't understand the last step. How does last step follows from proceeding one? I use that value of $s$ obtained but I couldn't reach the outcome given there.[image]

Comment: Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial.  To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typo, it should be $s = \frac{4t}{\sum_{i=1}^n (b_i-a_i)^2}$, not $s^2$. Plugging that in for $s$ yields
$$-st + \frac{s^2}{8} \sum_{i=1}^n (b_i-a_i)^2
= - \frac{4t^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n (b_i-a_i)^2} + \frac{6t^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n (b_i-a_i)^2} = -\frac{2t^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n (b_i-a_i)^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.